# RALLY: Determine a parent User Story's release

Tags: javascript, rally

In Rally we have the following story structure:

Parent Story 1
|__ Sub Story 1
|   |__ Child Story 1
|   |__ Child Story 2
|
|__ Sub Story 2
    |__ Child Story 3
    |__ Sub Story 3
         |*_* Child Story 4

I want to make a view of all Parent stories and what release they are currently scheduled in.  Once the Parent story has child stories it's release value is not editable because it is set in a lower story.  Is there a way to determine what release the story would be completed in with only making 1 call to Rally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution I have found is to do the following:

```
var epicLevelStories = {
    key: 'epics',
    type: 'hierarchicalrequirement',
    fetch: 'FormattedID,Name,ObjectID,Release'
    query: epicQuery,
    order: 'FormattedID'
};

var epicLevel2Stories = {
    key: 'epiclevel2',
    placeholder: '${epics.children?fetch=Name,FormattedID,Parent,Release}'
};

var epicLevel3Stories = {
    key: 'epiclevel3',
    placeholder: '${epiclevel2.children?fetch=Name,FormattedID,Parent,Release}'
};

var queryArray = [epicLevelStories, epicLevel2Stories, epicLevel3Stories];
rallyDataSource.findAll(queryArray, doStuffWithResults);
```

Once you get a result set (epiclevel#) that has no entries you know you have reached the bottom of the tree.

I'm guessing if epiclevel3 still has stories then you could build a new query array for the next 3 levels and recursively call the same "doStuffWithResults" method.  Just a thought.  I haven't tested that.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to get a list of a parent story's children to see what release they fall in 
you could use the following query.

`(Parent.Parent.FormattedID = ###PUT THE FORMATTED ID HERE###)`

If you want to experiment in your browser you can try the following URL.

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.26/hierarchicalrequirement.js?query=(Parent.Parent.FormattedID=###PUT_THE_FORMATTED_ID_HERE###)&fetch=Release&pretty=true

If you knew that the children stories would all be in the same release you could put a &pagesize=1 and look at the release for that single returned story while saving a bit of bandwidth.

One of the weird parts about this query is that you will have to know how deep the stories you want to retrieve are from the parent you are interested in. In the case of your example your hierarchy is two deep so in the query you use the Parent.Parent of the stories I am trying to retrieve.

Comment: Charles - Thanks for the response.  I've thought about this option, but the problem is that I don't know the depth of the child stories.   I've seen in the Epic Progress Summary App (http://www.rallydev.com/help/epic-progress) that you can do a few queries linked together, but you still have to decide the maximum depth to query.

Comment: You can always do `(Parent.FormattedID = S1)` or `(Parent.Parent.FormattedID = S1)` and so on until you have a huge or chain that will catch them all. 
We are aware of the inconvenience that this causes such as never knowing how deep the hierarchy is and having to hope you chained enough cases in the OR to get the full depth. We have some early ideas on ways to make this easier, but none of them will be in user hands anytime soon.

Comment: That's what I was planning on doing, but hoped that there was a better solution.  Is there an idea in the Rally Idea Manager that I can vote up for this?

Comment: We now have a [idea](http://ideas.rallydev.com/ct/ct_a_view_idea.bix?c=ideas&idea_id=4B11451B-24BB-4194-9236-ED2BA49C9991) for this.