# Rally: How the 'Release' filter in Rally is implemented?

Tags: release, rally, user-stories

We need to determine a top level story to be considered under a selected release if any of its child (or further child stories) are scheduled to be released in the selected release. Valuable replies would greatly help.

Answer (score 3):

Rally's WSAPI does not have an easy way to figure out aggregate information of children at the parent story level.

In order to determine which release(s) a parent story is in you will need to figure it out based upon the children stories.

There is a decent discussion of how to do this located in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586312/rally-determine-a-parent-user-storys-release) question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this app: http://developer.rallydev.com/help/epic-progress-app

It might not meet your exact requirements, but most of the code will be useful and you can tweak it to match your requirements.