# Report of Customer List that has all Defect based on the User Story's Release

Tags: rally

I would like to get a report or custom list that displays all the defects where the defect environment is Production and the parent/associated User Story's release matches the release drop-down on the custom screen.

I found this story and it's close I think, but not sure how to link it to the release drop-down and also not sure how to display the User Story the defect is related to.

[RALLY: Determine a parent User Story's release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586312/rally-determine-a-parent-user-storys-release)

The output should be the user story ID and Name along with the Defect ID and Name and possibly a few more columns.

I know I could do this via the API, but was trying to see if there is another way inside the existing Rally tools.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck!  I don't get to write apps as much as I'd like and I had some free time this afternoon so I whipped something up for you.  Just create a release scoped custom page and add this code to a Custom HTML app on that page.

The app includes a field picker to change the displayed set of fields.  I made a best guess at some useful ones to start with.  It also includes a control to enable printing and exporting.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>DefectsByStoryInRelease</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0/sdk.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Rally.onReady(function () {
        Ext.define('DefectsByStoryInRelease', {
            extend: 'Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp',
            componentCls: 'app',

            scopeType: 'release',

            onScopeChange: function () {
                Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.TreeStoreBuilder').build({
                    models: ['defect'],
                    autoLoad: true,
                    enableHierarchy: true,
                    filters: this._getFilters()
                }).then({
                    success: this._onStoreBuilt,
                    scope: this
                });
            },

            _onStoreBuilt: function (store) {
                var modelNames = ['defect'],
                        context = this.getContext(),
                        gridBoard = this.down('rallygridboard');

                if (gridBoard) {
                    gridBoard.destroy();
                }

                this.add({
                    xtype: 'rallygridboard',
                    height: this.getHeight() - ((this.getHeader() && this.getHeader().getHeight()) || 0),
                    context: context,
                    modelNames: modelNames,
                    toggleState: 'grid',
                    stateful: false,
                    plugins: [
                        {
                            ptype: 'rallygridboardfieldpicker',
                            headerPosition: 'left',
                            modelNames: modelNames,
                            stateful: true,
                            stateId: context.getScopedStateId('fields')
                        },
                        {
                            ptype: 'rallygridboardactionsmenu',
                            menuItems: [
                                {
                                    text: 'Export...',
                                    handler: function () {
                                        window.location = Rally.ui.grid.GridCsvExport.buildCsvExportUrl(
                                                this.down('rallygridboard').getGridOrBoard());
                                    },
                                    scope: this
                                },
                                {
                                    text: 'Print...',
                                    handler: function () {
                                        Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.TreeGridPrintDialog', {
                                            grid: this.down('rallygridboard').getGridOrBoard(),
                                            treeGridPrinterConfig: {
                                                largeHeaderText: 'Defects'
                                            }
                                        });
                                    },
                                    scope: this
                                }
                            ],
                            buttonConfig: {
                                iconCls: 'icon-export'
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    gridConfig: {
                        store: store,
                        columnCfgs: [
                            'Name',
                            'Requirement',
                            'State',
                            'Priority',
                            'Severity'
                        ]
                    }
                });
            },

            _getFilters: function () {
                var scope = this.getContext().getTimeboxScope(),
                        release = scope.getRecord(),
                        filters = [{
                            property: 'Environment',
                            value: 'Production'
                        }];

                if (release) {
                    filters = filters.concat([

                        {
                            property: 'Requirement.Release.Name',
                            value: release.get('Name')
                        },
                        {
                            property: 'Requirement.Release.ReleaseStartDate',
                            value: release.get('ReleaseStartDate')
                        },
                        {
                            property: 'Requirement.Release.ReleaseDate',
                            value: release.get('ReleaseDate')
                        }
                    ]);
                } else {
                    filters.push({
                        property: 'Requirement.Release',
                        value: null
                    });
                }

                return filters;
            }
        });


        Rally.launchApp('DefectsByStoryInRelease', {
            name: "DefectsByStoryInRelease",
            parentRepos: ""
        });

    });
</script>


<style type="text/css">
    .app {
        /* Add app styles here */
    }

</style>
```

Comment: Awesome!!  Thanks so much for building this.  I  always love learning new ways to improve Rally apps, and have learned a number of things from your example.

While this is what I needed, there an error is thrown on a few projects when changing the release:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
extjs4script-sdk-async-gnt.combined.js.h-559582355.pack:6672 POST https://beacon.rallydev.com/beacon/ 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Any ideas what to look at on the release record or what could be causing this?  I can investigate further.

Comment: that error is a happening while reporting client metrics data to rally.  when it happens does it totally break the app?  or does it just console log an error and continue on successfully?  we've heard a few other reports of similar errors so i'd be curious to hear more...

Comment: It does not continue updating, and just stops working.  If you need additional details please let me know.

Comment: Kyle, just to provide an update.  I tested this the next day and everything was working.  The team that requested this has been using it, and have not had any issues either.  Thanks again for your help with this!

Comment: glad to hear it's working for you again.  it's possible it was an issue with our client metrics service on our side.  it still seems like that shouldn't torch the entire app though.  i'll continue to investigate